# not able to make connection using javamail api

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-mail, store

I am trying to make connection to the mailserver using java mail api, with user loginId password and the host name. But if any one of the id fails to make connection then the following ids also fails to authorize even if they have correct credentials.

Do I've to close the store values after the loop.

```
      sessions = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
      store = sessions.getStore(emailAccType);
      store.connect(emailHost,emailId, emailPwd);
```

What i need to close in finally block of try/catch.

for the following error.

`javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:161)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
    at com.scheduler.utils.QuartzImplementation.<init>(QuartzImplementation.java:77)
    at com.scheduler.utils.SchedulerRedirect.execute(SchedulerRedirect.java:31)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.simpleCommand(Protocol.java:360)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:104)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.getPort(POP3Store.java:214)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:157)`

for the first time it's executing but if one fails then this problem arise.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[Refer the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088000/java-mail-provides-access-to-another-pop3-accounts-inbox)

Please ensure you've read the java mail API FAQs completely.

Comment: Yes i did , but what exactly the problem is i am not getting it. why does it fail the connection if one fails

Comment: Please call  Session.getInstance(properties); instead of Session.getDefaultInstance(properties) and make sure that a new session object is created for each account

Comment: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?.. This may be because you're not connecting to the right port. Default port for pop3 is 110 and for a secured SSL pop3 connection, connect to port 995

Comment: Both the this i 've tried but still failure. and now i'm facing new problem as 'javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Mailbox locked'  with same code.